# Insert only if row with non uniqe foreign key doesn't already exist in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table A

| id | field |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | valueA |
| 2 | valueB |
| ... | ... |

and a table B with a reference to table A

| id | fk_table_a | field_a | field_b | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I wanna insert something on table B only if it doesn't have already any dataset that has a reference to A (via fk_table_a)

Unfortunately the foreign fk_table_a key isn't unique and i can't change this fact, so it is potential possible to insert another entry with same foreign key. But i don't want this in my case.

I use INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement to insert a whole bunch of rows into the table B
... the select for this is a bit more extensive but it looks something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_b (fk_table_a, field_a, field_b, ...)
   SELECT ot1.id_table_a, ot2.field_a, ot3.field_b
   FROM other_table_1 ot1, 
   JOIN other_table_2 ot2 ...
   JOIN other_table_3 ot3 ...
   ....
#only insert the current dataset if it ot1.id_table_a doesnt exist already in table_b!
```

So for any dataset from the select i don't wanna have an entry in table_b, if there is already a dataset with the same fk_table_a ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a WHERE clause to check non-existance of the id in other_table_1 may fix your problem.  Try this,

```
INSERT INTO table_b (fk_table_a, field_a, field_b, ...)
  SELECT ot1.id_table_a, ot2.field_a, ot3.field_b
  FROM other_table_1 ot1, 
     JOIN other_table_2 ot2 ...
     JOIN other_table_3 ot3 ...
  WHERE ot1.id_table_a NOT IN (SELECT fk_table_a FROM table_b)
```

Comment: Hmmm seems to work once ... before i had 2002 records in DB and after 4406 .. if i delete one, i would expect to get 4406 again since the one missing is-readded again ... but thats not the case ... strange ...

Comment: Does the select query return the record has to be added?